# Convert a Single Column to a Correlation matrix like form

Tags: r

Hi Guys I'm interested in converting a simple column with a data frame in a kind of matrix in the style of a correlation matrix, in order to apply a "for" cycle later making requests to a database

My input data:

```
DATA
1664
1790
1678
1789
1778
1871
```

Desired Ouptput:

```
DATA    1664    1790    1678    1789    1778    1871
1664    1664    1790    1678    1789    1778    1871
1790    1664    1790    1678    1789    1778    1871
1678    1664    1790    1678    1789    1778    1871
1789    1664    1790    1678    1789    1778    1871
1778    1664    1790    1678    1789    1778    1871
1871    1664    1790    1678    1789    1778    1871
```

Comment: You can try `cbind(df[, 1], sapply(df[, 1], "*", df[, 1] == df[, 1]))`.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats exactly i want it.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `list` full of single values to a right-hand side of an assignment and it will fill all rows. I.e.:

```
dat[as.character(dat$DATA)] <- as.list(dat$DATA)
dat
#  DATA 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
#1 1664 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
#2 1790 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
#3 1678 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
#4 1789 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
#5 1778 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
#6 1871 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- read.table(text="DATA
1664
1790
1678
1789
1778
1871", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in base R using a for loop:

```
DATA <-c(1664, 1790, 1678, 1789, 1778, 1871)
list <- list()

for(i in 1:length(DATA)){
  list[[i]] <- rep(DATA[i], length(DATA))
}

df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Transposing and repeating the rows:

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(c(1664, 1790, 1678, 1789, 1778, 1871)))
df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), ncol(df)),]
```

**Output**:

```
      V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
1   1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
1.1 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
1.2 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
1.3 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
1.4 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
1.5 1664 1790 1678 1789 1778 1871
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(purrr)

data = c(1664,
         1790,
         1678,
         1789,
         1778,
         1871)

map_dfc(data,~rep(.,length(data)))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1664  1790  1678  1789  1778  1871
2  1664  1790  1678  1789  1778  1871
3  1664  1790  1678  1789  1778  1871
4  1664  1790  1678  1789  1778  1871
5  1664  1790  1678  1789  1778  1871
6  1664  1790  1678  1789  1778  1871
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `replicate`

```
t(replicate(nrow(dat), dat$DATA))
```